# To give each edit own version history

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, edits, revisions-list

I read [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1063646/list) to my question right from its publication. He edited his answer about 5 minutes after his first edit.

The version control system makes it very hard to see what has been changed in the version history.

**Please, give each independent edit its own tab in the version history.**

SO includes edits at the moment to one history instance if you have edited files in a short time period. This behavior should be changed.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this behavior is a byproduct of counting all edits in a five-minute window as one edit. This feature was created because there was a common pattern of quickly answering a question with two or three sentenced and maybe a link. Then the user would immediately edit their answer with more detail, and also correct typos and other errors.

The problem comes when you factor in the fact that a post rolls over to Community Wiki after 5(?) edits from the original author. Since it's very easy to make these 5 edits in the initial period of 'forming' the post, people wanted a way to retain ownership and reputation from these posts. The solution has been collapsing all edits within a 5-minute window into 1 edit.

If it's possible to retain the multiple-edits-count-as-one feature and still have a revision entry for each edit, then I support this feature request.

Comment: Perhaps have the edits within 5 minutes not count towards the total that make the post CW?

Comment: Right. It would be trickier to implement, but it would make the revision list better to use.

Comment: I'm sure it was also mentioned somewhere (by Mr Atwood) that the each revision is a new full copy of the markup in the database, so tracking the first 5 minutes would increase the size of the database a fair bit..

Comment: @Kyle: I support your last point in your answer.

Comment: the edits within the 5 minute interval DO NOT COUNT and NEVER HAVE COUNTED toward the CW threshold.

Comment: Sorry, I stand corrected. However, what was the reason for merging all edits in a 5-minute window, because I KNOW it wasn't always like that.

Comment: @Kyle: it worked that way since at least last Sept. - i mentioned it in a FAQ entry at that time. I can't really recall a time when it didn't work that way...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this as much of a problem, those little edits are limited by the captcha system and rarely contain much actual content change.

I would rather less noise and complexity over having this fine grained detail.