# Is there a grace period for correction of edits?

Tags: support, edits, revisions-list, grace-period

I just edited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382884/how-can-i-disable-a-constraint) twice, because I had left a typo in the title after the first edit. In the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1382884/list), both edits seem to have been merged into one, using the edit summary from the second edit.

Is this on purpose? Is there a grace period for correcting edits?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you first post you have a grace period of 5 minutes. Edits in that time do not constitute a trackable edit on the history.

The same applies when you edit something after 5 minutes: it begins a new 5 minute grace period.

Comment: I know about the grace period after the first posting, but the other one is new to me; especially when editing *someone else's post*. Do you have a source?

Comment: Never mind, found it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1159/ Thanks.