# Are edits to answers ever grouped together?

Tags: support, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a grace period for correction of edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20441/is-there-a-grace-period-for-correction-of-edits)

I understant that editing one's answer > 10 times results in the answer becoming a community wiki.  Is it possible that "quick-fire" edits would ever be grouped together into one edit?  I know that sounds ridiculous, but I'm just about certain that I edited my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5169252/revisions) more than 2 times.

Comment: The [answer is yes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20441/is-there-a-grace-period-for-correction-of-edits) - there is a 5 minute period after an edit, during which all subsequent edits from that author will be counted as the same edit.

Comment: That sounds like an answer to me.  Can you so post so I can close this out?? :)

Comment: And, in rare cases, when *someone else* starts editing within that grace period, this might even accidentally overwrite edits, and show that "edits" were created by [the wrong person](http://superuser.com/questions/251370/adding-file-type-to-ack-permanently#comments-251370).