# Undo answer edit

Tags: support, edits, wrong-answers

I edited an answer and saved it.  Then I realized my change was based on my own mis-conceptions about the answer.  Now, I can't undo the edit because when I edit it again and undo the changes it says:

> Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because: Nothing appears to have
>   changed

This is what I edited:
[WiX: How to register application to start when Windows launches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052698/wix-how-to-register-application-to-start-when-windows-launches)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can click the rollback link when you are viewing the revisions of the answer if you have the [Edit Questions And Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) privilege (2000 reputation on graduates sites).  I did this for you. :)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I was looking for a way to roll it back and could not find a 'rollback' on that.  Maybe I went to the wrong page, didn't look hard enough or it's not there.  Any way, thanks for rolling it back for me.

Comment: If you click the time it was edited (where it says "edited 2 days ago" above my name), you can see the revisions for the question or answer.  There is a rollback option in there.  You might not see it (i'm not sure) since you have under 2000 rep.

Comment: If you don’t have edit permissions and submit an edit for peer review, and then realize that the edit was a mistake, you don’t get that ‘rollback’ option, and re-editing it just to undo the changes will just give you an error saying it doesn't look like you changed anything.

Comment: @BrandonKelly  I am in precisely this same situation.  This appears to be a flaw on the site.

Comment: In the current version I don't see anywhere `rollback` button. I am speaking about `dba.stackexchange`

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov you need 2000 reputation to edit and rollback.  You won't see the rollback link unless you have that privilege.

Comment: 10x, @KyleTrauberman. I ask because I make edit on wrong answer. Ok, I go for 2k, so I can fix my mistake next time :)

Comment: You can edit the post again, change nothing in the body, and ask for "reject this edit" in the edit summary field

Comment: I accidentally edit other person's answer instead of mine to introduce the newest solution. Since I don't have the privilege to rollback yet, so what I can do is edit the answer again, put comment "Reject this edit" as @MarkJeronimus suggestion. Then explain my mistake inside the answer.

Answer (score 4):

This likely happened because when you tried to edit it again, it was [within 5 minutes of your previous edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20441/is-there-a-grace-period-for-correction-of-edits), so they got combined into one edit. The system then noticed that the resulting edit would be identical to the previous revision (your original post) and rejected it.