# I edit my answers a lot. How can I prevent myself from forfeiting credit due to "community wiki"?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, community-wiki

I make a lot of edits to my posts, as I tend to answer, edit for grammar, and then refine it as I do more research. It's simply my style of learning while also answering. My posts are almost all very high quality, long, and well researched with a high acceptance rate. But my style of large amounts of small to medium sized edits ensures that I forfeit any long term point gain. There really isn't a way for me to produce the answers I do without breaking the community wiki edit limit.

Is there a way to make edits that don't bump or count toward the limit? How easy is it to get a post un-wikied? Is it a problem if I try to flag every post I make to be exempt from the edit limit? I don't want or need for my edits to bump the post, I just want and need to be able to iteratively improve them.

This is a really good example of a post of mine suffering from this problem [V8 and ECMAScript differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873981/v8-and-ecmascript-differences)

Comment: Kind of looks like you're liveblogging. Why not edit when you have more than a sentence to change?

Comment: Why should i have to if I'm improving my answer? I don't want to bump it, I just want to improve it.

Comment: A draft is saved when you are writing your answer. You said that you edit your answers a lot. There is absolutely nothing wrong with that. That's really good. 

The Problem:: But these edits aren't hours apart. The edits are *minutes* apart.

Stop hitting the "Save edits". Your draft is saved.
(http://i.stack.imgur.com/N2v5o.png)

Look at the live preview below the edit block and read ... and read ... and read again. The only difference now is that you are not hitting the Save edit button.

Comment: There'd be less need for this if they'd implement a decent drafts system....

Comment: Many of them are hours apart. And Many of them are months apart. And there's different questions. Why is this question marked as answered and written off? If this is a duplicate then why is there still no good answer?

Comment: More to the point: why am I considering whether I should improve the quality of my answers?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8654/so-is-too-eager-to-turn-my-edited-answers-into-community-wiki

Answer (score 22):

With the exception of edits made within the [first 5 minutes of posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20441/is-there-a-grace-period-for-correction-of-edits), there isn't a way to make edits that don't count towards the edit limit before conversion to CW or don't bump the question. The idea that edits bump a post and get fresh eyes on it is one of the core features of Stack Exchange.

Moderators can remove CW from a post, but I wouldn't count on moderators supporting your special case over the long term.

If you can't work within the limit, I suggest composing your answer elsewhere first (Google Doc?) and posting it on Stack Overflow when it is reasonably complete.

Comment: Actually, edits in the 5-minute window after another edit (by the same person) are also non-counting.

Comment: This isn't enough. It's not enough for me to keep the quality of answer I produce. Especially in an industry where the answer literally changes within 6 months. Please reopen this question as this hasn't been answered even remotely adequately for an entire category of discussion.

Comment: @Brandon If the answer changes within 6 months, can you make do with a single edit once the answer changes?

Comment: Perhaps. Perhaps I could organize a stack overflow memoirs and write that once per three months.

Comment: @BrandonBenvie You can be sarcastic if you like, but I'm still trying to figure out how an answer changing over time requires multiple rapid edits in a short amount of time. For example, looking at the example you gave, I see a lot of edits on November 22 that likely could've been batched together.

Comment: Perhaps. Perhaps I could organize a stack overflow memoirs and write that once per three months. Technically though, Brendan Eich writes around 300 responses per month on the ES-discuss mailing list. Around 400 high quality messages are posted on that list per month. Not by randoms or people with big opinions. people at google and Mozilla and Opera and MS, discussing stuff landing in browsers 72 hours. anyone can read it but the point is that to do my best conveying my summation of those ongoing ddiscuss, next month implementation browsers is not possible with stack overflows current system.

Comment: @BrandonBenvie It's possible if you're willing to accept the fact that doing so will possibly cost you some rep. I honestly sympathize and admire what you're trying to do. It's no doubt a lot of work. But unfortunately it's also a pretty narrow edge case for how the system is designed. I don't think it's worth changing how it works, so I'm just trying to make some suggestions for how you could continue doing what you're doing within the existing limits.

Comment: This is what I do and love. I want my share if SO credit for it but whatever. That's less important to me the just having a good answer. I'm not willing to fight a stupid ass system with no ability to recognize and eventually fix its problems. I

Comment: "doom is coming"? Really? Isn't that a bit melodramatic?

Answer (score 6):

You're not forfeiting credit. You're just giving over heavily edited and attention draining posts over to the community.

Stack Exchange trades in attention as its major currency. Other people reading the work and judging it based on merit, technical accuracy and flair. Every time you edit you push your post back to the top of the queue and back in front of potentially newer eyeballs and possibly new upvotes.

If you can [bunch up your rapid edit sessions inside five minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9090/is-there-an-editing-grace-period-on-answers-after-they-have-been-posted), then all that will show is the single revision. Or try learning some tantric type editing composure, loading them up into bigger revisions instead of sputtering them out over a scattered period.

[Moderators can remove community wiki status from a post at their discretion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/is-there-a-way-to-remove-community-wiki-status). But they won't look too kindly on you if you go flagging your posts thinking that you deserve some exemption from the system mechanics.

You can add your voice to the chorus of those wanting [a "minor edit" no bump feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26483/could-we-have-the-ability-to-mark-a-change-as-minor-in-questions-or-answers) which will also handily make sure edits fly under the radar to allow all sorts of anarchy and doom and the coming of removed transparency. Next thing you know we're all [John Travolta](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119094/).

Every busy edit makes it less "yours" and more "ours". Share the communism and embrace the peer-review.