# If an answer is edited will the "Edited at XXXX" notice always be shown?

Tags: support, edits

In the answers to this question: [How can I change the view outside the main thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594694/how-can-i-change-the-view-outside-the-main-thread/11594706#comment15345174_11594706)

One poster felt that another had copied his answer. He claimed that the alleged copied answer had been edited, but there was no "Edited at XXXXX" notice next to the name of poster. He also has linked to another of his answers that he indicates was edited but also does not show this notice.

Is it possible that an answer can be edited and not be displaying this notice?

Comment: Related: [Make first draft of a new answer part of the permanent revision history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138017/make-first-draft-of-a-new-answer-part-of-the-permanent-revision-history)

Comment: Incidentally, I've seen only a tiny handful of legit "he copied my answer" complaints. They tend to be pretty blatant. When the code, text, and links are different, crying "he ripped me off!" is... Lame. Flag these comments for moderator deletion, er, "review".

Comment: @Shog9 will do.

Comment: @Shog9 I agree. But in a lot of cases it's not about stealing someone's answer. It's about being the first to post an "answer coming soon" post to try to get the enlightened badge, then googling the answer, then updating the answer within the grace period. I've seen that far more often than content theft, but of course I can't prove it because they have five minutes to improve the answer a thousand fold, with no trace that they touched it.

Comment: @Aaron: if you see that (not just a brief initial answer but an actual *non-answer* posted and then edited), take a screenshot and flag. Also down-vote. If it's quickly improved, there's probably not much harm - but if someone makes a habit of this, could be worth taking them aside.

Comment: @Shog9 I'd have to be pretty pre-cognitive to take a screen shot. :-) They don't always start out in such an obvious form, and once thy've been edited... I think the only way to stop this abuse, sadly, is to abolish the badges. Aside from the badge (and the theft cases), there's little motivation to do it.

Comment: @Aaron: well, if it's *not* obvious (e.g. it looks like an answer) then this is a lot closer to the classic FGITW "problem". FWIW, the new real-time updates actually make detecting this a lot easier, since if the post is edited while you're looking at it, you get a little notification at the top of the answer - even if the edit is made within the grace period. Great time to hit Alt+PrtSc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible that an answer can be edited and not be displaying this notice?

Yes, it is. But only if edited within 5 minutes of the time it was first posted and only by the same poster. This is known as the [grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20441/is-there-a-grace-period-for-correction-of-edits).

Note that there is some contention about this and there are requests to have [the *first* edit always show up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138017/make-first-draft-of-a-new-answer-part-of-the-permanent-revision-history), regardless of whether they were made during the grace period.