# Is it possible to view all of the edits to an answer post?

Tags: support, edits

As the title says, is it possible to view all of the changes made to an answer post? I have found that clicking on the time stamp of the edit shows a view of an edit. Is this only the latest edit or does it show all of them? Is it possible to stop an edit from being displayed in this window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That link shows all edits to the question.

The only exception are subsequent edits done by the same author within a grace period (5 minutes, if I remember correctly). Those are are collapsed and only the last of those subsequent edits will show up.

This can be the initial author, so a post might look like it was never edited when indeed it was modified by the original author.

Comment: It's not just the original author.  Any edit to any post where the previous edit was from the same person and is within 5 minutes will result in the edits being merged, and only generating a single revision entry.

Comment: @Servy: I *did* know that, at least subconciously, I even used that a few times. Thanks for the corrections. (fixed now).

Comment: So there is nowhere to view edits made within the first five mins?

Comment: @Pezzzz: that's right, any embarrassing omissions or errors that the original author fixes within the first 5 minutes are hidden forever.

Comment: or when the author changes the answer so that it now fulfills the question and calls me out on not reading his answer correctly, I can't prove him wrong :(. Anyway thanks for you help, can't +1 without more rep :(

Comment: @Pezzzz that's why you need to find some spelling error to fix in an edit for some posts so that any edits the OP makes can't be merged in the revision history.

Comment: @Pezzzz regarding _author calling you out_, there is a feature request you might be interested in: [Make first draft of a new answer part of the permanent revision history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138017/165773)

Answer (score 3):

Clicking the view edit link will show every edit made, except for those the original poster makes during the [5 minute Grace Period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20441/is-there-a-grace-period-for-correction-of-edits) (and any edits made which came before an edit by the original poster during the 5 minute grace period).

Edits after the first five minutes (or after the first non-OP edit in the first five minutes) will be *smushed* within 5 minute grace periods for the last editor of any post as well. The grace period smushing, plus suggested edits, can lead to an interesting edit histories.