# After my question is downvoted and edited will it still reach users?

Tags: support, edits, bump

Say that I have asked a question on MSE and then it is downvoted, after I edit it to form a better question will my question move up the queue of questions so that people can read it again and upvote it?

Comment: Votes are not relevant. Edit will bump the question back to the top of "last active" questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any edited question will appear in the top of [active questions list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active) and in the top of homepage if [sorted by active questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=active), unless the edit you made was in the [grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20441/is-there-a-grace-period-for-correction-of-edits) after your edit. Grace period lasts for 5 mins, in which you can improve your edit.

Comment: Just a minor clarification, So everytime I edit will it move up in the Active question list ??

Comment: @Meta Yes, if this edit hasn't occurred in the grace period (after an edit on the question there is a grace period of 5 mins, in which you can improve your edit and correct mistakes which you could make during editing).

Comment: Does the same apply to answers ?

Comment: @Meta Yes, it does. I modified my answer 5 mins ago and you can see your question in the lists I mentioned and on the bottom right of your q you can see: "modified 5 mins ago nicael". - http://i.stack.imgur.com/gqrtL.png

Comment: Yeah just now noticed. I will upvote the answer when I gain sufficient reputation.